# How to plot all values in google column chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, plot, google-visualization

I'm trying to plot a Google column chart  from the data where  there is a huge range between the highest values and the lowest values.The chart is plotting correctly for the large values but when the values are too small  it is not plotting any column for that values.I want to plot all values no matter it is 0.02 or 5000 .If i use the option `logScale:true` then it plots all the values but the chart starts from 1 and the values less than 1 goes to negative Y Axis. How to solve  this problem without increasing the height of the chart so that it starts from 0 point and plots all the values including  negative values? I also tried to set

```
 viewWindow: {
        max:100
        min:0
    }
```

but did not work!
Here is my code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'profit'],
          ['2004',  1000,      4],
          ['2005',  0.1,       -460],
          ['2006',  660,       2],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},

       vAxis:{logScale:true ,

          viewWindowMode:'explicit',
    viewWindow: {
        max:100,
       min:0
    }}

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any values less than `(axis range max - axis range min) / (chart area height in pixels)` will have columns smaller than 1px high, changing the height of the column to something larger is distorting the relative size of the data.  If you are willing to live with the distortions, there are a few tricks you can use; I made up a few examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/b4yCL/.  Will any of those work for you?

Comment: I have very little knowledge about java script so I am overwhelmed seeing the code for 4 charts together.I am plotting chart from  json data,can you please create a jsfiddle for me only for the char number 5?I will be highly glad if you explain little more about the chart5.